# Why do I get two lines of output from this code?

Tags: ruby

why does the following ruby program prints the output for two times?

```
a = Proc.new do
  class A
    def initialize d
      @c = d
    end

    def print
      p @c
    end
  end

  b = A.new(2)
  p b.print
end

a.call
```

Real output

```
2
2
```

Expected output

```
2
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you or do you not expect it to print two lines? Because it does print two lines.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with proc

Comment: But why does it print two lines?. please help me

Comment: @Vivakkumar: because that's what you have in the code. Two prints.

Comment: BTW, in Ruby there's also a global function called [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-print). You should pick another name for your method to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Thanks serigo for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does the following ruby program prints the output for two times?

This is the first print

```
p @c
```

Result of this will become return value of method `print`, which will then be printed in turn

```
p b.print
```

Method `p` returns the value printed. That's how you get two lines with the same output.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Proc.new do
  class A
    def initialize d
      @c = d
    end

    def print
     p @c
    end
  end

  b = A.new(2)
  b.print #you need just to call method print
end

a.call
```

Comment: The method is called `print`. It'd be weird if it didn't actually print, one would argue :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sure, my mistake) Thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, `p` both prints its argument and returns it, so `b.print` both prints and returns 2; then `p b.print` prints 2 again.

Answer (score 0):

The command "p" on Ruby means you wants to "print" something...Your code does the "p" command twice. Just remove the unwanted and it will work.

```
a = Proc.new do
  class A
    def initialize d
      @c = d
    end

    def print
     p @c #FIRST PRINT
    end
  end

  b = A.new(2)
  p b.print #SECOND PRINT
end

a.call
```